# UITapGestureRecognizer in the subview of a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a view controller that has a UIScrollView IBOutlet hooked up via storyboard. This view controller has a `property` that holds on to another view controller. I then add the view from this view controller into the UIScrollView as follows:

```
[scrollView addSubview:self.derpController.view];
```

Within `derpController`, I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` as follows:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleFingerTap:)]];
```

Now, the problem that I run into is that the `singleFingerTap:` selector only gets called in the area within the starting area of the `UIScrollView`. That is, if I scroll the view and tap in a location that was not initially visible, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not triggered.

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this issue.

**EDIT:**
On the iPad implementation, the tap gesture is actually recognized a bit beyond the initial startup screen, but it does not cover the entire subview in scrollview.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but: Are you absolutely, one hundred percent sure that the view you added really extends past the `frame` of the scroll view?

Comment: The view is composed of a grid of UIImages and they all show up in the scroll view beyond the default view, which (to me) indicates that the entire view is added.